# Sony Camera Remote API - GPS information, location geotagging

Tags: camera, gps, sony

I want to develop an app which can add geotag/location information to the photo when saving the data to memory.
But before that , I have to know if there are APIs could make this happen.
Who can tell me if there are APIs like this or not?